How to setup LLVM on Windows to run lli/llc
Recently I installed LLVM on my Windows 10 machine through their installer provided in LLVM repo (LLVM-18.1.8-win64.exe). I checked "Add to PATH" when installing and everything went OK.
However, when I try to run llc (docs) or lli (docs) from command line, it says it's "not recognized as an internal or external command".
I checked that path to LLVM's bin folder is set in the PATH, but in the folder there is no file llc.exe, lli.exe or anything like that. I tried to reinstall it and restart the computer, but with no outcome.
Did I missed something? Is there so other way to run llc/lli on Windows?
